# Needing assistance with COUNT, getting unexpected results

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, count

I am having to join a dozen tables to get specific fields needed for a SSRS report.  One of the table joins that is necessary also adds 'duplicate' records.

The records of course aren't actually duplicates as far as the DB is concerned because of one field that makes them unique.  So I created a tmp table off my main query and didn't include that nefarious field (I will dub Column D)- this query has me in knots.

I believed this would make my task simple.

My temp table now only has the following (anonymized):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    jt.A                        [ColumnA]
    ,jt.B                       [ColumnB]
    ,jt.C                       [ColumnC]
    ,COUNT(*)                   [TotalCount]
INTO
    #CountsTbl
FROM
    #JoinsTbl jt    
GROUP BY
    jt.A    
    ,jt.B                           
    ,jt.C
```

When I join this table with another to view the results the Count is still wrong, any records that have the same data in A,B,C are duplicating even though Column D wasn't included in the tmp table and I used SELECT DISTINCT.

```
+---------+------------+------------+---------+------------+
| ColumnA |  ColumnB   |  ColumnC   | ColumnD | TotalCount |
+---------+------------+------------+---------+------------+
| 0123    | 01/01/2016 | 01/31/2016 |   ABC   |     1      |
+---------+------------+------------+---------+------------+
| 0123    | 02/01/2016 | 02/28/2016 |   ABC   |     2      |
+---------+------------+------------+---------+------------+
| 0123    | 02/01/2016 | 02/28/2016 |   XYZ   |     2      |
+---------+------------+------------+---------+------------+
```

The logic I am missing is escaping me and I have been working on this query for so long I think I need a few other eyes to look at it. In the above example this is what I get when I join, even though the COUNT has already been done in the previous tmp table.  The first row has a correct count, the 2nd and 3rd I want to only have a count of 1 as I don't want the COUNT to look at column D, just A-C.

I am using SQL Server 2014

This is my first post so please let me know if I need to include more information.  I wasn't successful in finding a meaningful answer - perhaps I am asking the wrong questions.

Thanks

Comment: So, I see a "group by" based on column A, B and C. And there are two records there having same values in A, B and C columns. The only difference is in Column D, but you dont want to check that column?

Comment: I am not really sure what the issue is here. I suspect it is because there are multiple rows in the various tables. Distinct won't help you hear unless you are using count(Distinct SomeColumn). At least for me I would like to see some sample data (not real information) representing the problem you are facing.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli ColumnD is the problem, I need the information in that column for the report but I don't want it to be included when I count.  I just want the count to be based on rows that are unique to columns A-C.

Comment: @SeanLange - I have meeting in 5 mins, I will try to post something that would assist but my total query is over 160 lines long and pulling from millions of records so I am not sure how to not make this too cumbersome and yet helpful to you and others here.  I am commenting out multiple lines trying to figure out where the logic is broken and it appears to at least START with this COUNT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this may not be super helpful as I didn't have time to go into more detail on the query, etc - but I did find my own solution to the problem.

My primary tmp table (I didn't post it here) has a number of complex joins - (which need cleaned up to improve performance) followed by a few more tmp tables that join to it for aggregates.  Those 3 tmp tables join to my main query to display the results I need for the SSRS report.  There are 8 user parameters and 3 are optional but the fields for the report were set in stone and causing most of my aggregate headaches.

What I ended up doing was removing 'ColumnD' from the first large tmp table and performed the SELECT DISTINCT on that table.

The next tmp table was the one I did a mock up of in my question.  I was able to get 'accurate' COUNTS after the above change.  I use the quotes because all the COUNTS were at 1 because ColumnB and C are dates and they made each row unique.  Needless to say it was the step in the right direction.

I removed the date fields (I had them there just to be able to see if I was getting duplicates) and pulled in 2 columns that were Keys from 2 tables I joined in the previous tmp table and below is the mock up of how it works:

```
SELECT
    jt.FKEY1                            [AccountKEY]
    ,jt.FKEY2                           [CodeKEY]
    ,COUNT(*)                           [TotalCount]
--INTO
--  #CountsTbl
FROM
    #JoinsTbl jt    
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
    (jt.AccountKEY) 
    ,(jt.CodeKEY)
ORDER BY
    jt.CodeKEY
    ,jt.AccountKEY
```

The resulting tmp table had the COUNTs I needed.

Thanks to those that asked questions - and especially thanks to the many anonymous other posts that I read to help in researching for this query

Answer (score 0):

You have number 2 in 2nd and 3rd rows because that is how many rows ABC with values `0123    | 02/01/2016 | 02/28/2016`

To avoid that problem you have two choices:

1. In the counting query include column `D`, then you will always have 1 (unless all 4 columns are duplicated.)
2. In the query, producing result, you exclude column `D` completely, or use aggregation like MIN/MAX.

BTW both cases might be incorrect. It depends on what REALLY you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I guess my confusion comes in from where/how the COUNT works (in the background the nuts and bolts of the whole operation).  Column D wasn't in the query with the COUNT but it was in the tmp table that my COUNT query joined with.  And then it also appears in the above example presumably after I do a join with the COUNT query.  What did the trick was removing ColumnD from the initial tmp table, then doing the COUNT and then I added ColumnD at a later point in another join.

Comment: `COUNT` works fine. The question is "what results do you expect?".

Comment: I expected that with a SELECT DISTINCT the count would only see one of the rows with values | 0123 | 02/01/2016 | 02/28/2016 | As I didn't include ColumnD in the COUNT query.  My confusion comes from either misunderstanding how COUNT works or misunderstanding how SELECT DISTINCT works in this query.  I got my results to work with the answer I posted by using a different method.  I must say I am still not understanding what was wrong with my first attempt.

Comment: In your example you have 2 records with values ` | 0123 | 02/01/2016 | 02/28/2016` because you do not include column `D` these records are not counted as individual. Your current query answers the question "How many duplicate records have ABC fields for a particular D field"